# How to load mage_sales_flat_quote_item_option this table in Magento collection?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am very new to magento. Anyone can help me to load `mage_sales_flat_quote_item_option` this table in Magento collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->getCollection();
```

**EDIT**

The question was asked in a comment as to how to get a single property value from every model in the collection:

```
$collection->getColumnValues('your_column_name');
```

Comment: Thanks drew hunter. Can you help me once again. How to get a single field in this table by using this magento collection.

Comment: A single field from each model in the collection or a specific field from a particular model in the collection?